# Running PowerShell script on VSTS deployment group

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, azure-devops, release-management

I am configuring a deployment group phase inside my release definition at VSTS.

I added a PowerShell script task that is supposed to start a process (.exe console app) on the target machine.

I have tested the PowerShell script manually on the target PC and it is working great:

```
start-process -filepath c:\myfolder\myprogram.exe
```

But when the release runs, the script seems not to be working. It executes properly but my process is not initiated.

There is no error message on the release log.

How can I fix that?

Comment: what does the script look like?

Comment: To remove the previous agent, you can run config.cmd remove command. (1. Open Command Prompt as administrator 2. Go to agent folder, such as cd C:\vstsagent\A1 3. call .\config.cmd remove)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deployment group agent must be running as Interactive mode. Article: [Configure the agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/getting-started/machine-group-agents)

1. Download agent (Agent queues admin page> Click Download agent)
2. Run Command Line as administrator
3. Run `.\config.cmd --machinegroup` command
4. Specify Server URL, PAT token, Project Name, Deployment Group Name, Agent name
5. Press Enter (N) when it asks **if you want to run the agent as a service**
6. Call `.\run.cmd` to start agent
7. Modify release definition, specify that deployment group for **Run on deployment group**.

Comment: let me understand what I will be doing here: When I first created my deployment group I was given a script to run on my target servers. I assume that script was to download and install the vstsagent, right? Now, the procedure you are suggesting will register a new agent (with interactive mode turned on). When it is done, what should I do with the old agent? How do I uninstall it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the script would download and configure the vsts agent, but it is running as service. To remove it, you can run config.cmd remove command. (1. Open Command Prompt as administrator 2. Go to agent folder, such as cd C:\vstsagent\A1 3. call .\config.cmd remove)

Answer (score 1):

--machinegroup no longer support in the Agent installation,

So go with below,

```
  .\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "{Deployment Group Name}" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work "{Working Folder}" --url "{VSTS/Azure DevOps URL}" --projectname "{Project Name}" --auth PAT --token "{Token generated from azure DevOps portal with relevant release permissions}"
```